# C++ class termination

Tags: c++, class, events

I have declared a class and instantiated a class in one and expected it to fire

```
~CLog();
```

But for some reason, it does not. Does anybody see any obvious errors why this could happen?

I declared the class within a void that ends, so it SHOULD fire, I think.
I do not destroy the class explicitely, but I simply expected it to go out of out scope automatically and terminate.

```
#pragma once
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class CLog 
{
  public:
    CLog(wstring filename);
    ~CLog();
    void WriteString(wstring uString);
  private:
    wofstream m_stream;
    wstring m_sPath;
};

#include "log.h";
#include "strhelper.h"

#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>

wstring m_sText=L"";
wstring m_sPath=L"";

CLog::CLog(wstring uPath) 
{
    m_sPath=uPath;
}
void CLog::WriteString(wstring uString)
{
    m_sText+=uString;
    m_sText+=L"\n";
}
CLog::~CLog()
{

    if (FileExists(m_sPath))
    {
        DeleteFile(m_sPath);
    }

    //open for appending
    m_stream.imbue(std::locale(std::locale::empty(), new std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t,0x10ffff,std::generate_header>));
    m_stream.open(m_sPath,fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::app); 

    m_stream << m_sText.c_str();

    m_stream.close();
}
```

I am using `Clog` like this

```
void foo() {
  wstring sLogPath;
  sLogPath=GetSpecialFolderDesktop() + L"\\load.log";
  CLog *pLog = new CLog(sLogPath);
  pLog->WriteString(L"Something);
}
```

I am using VC2010.

Comment: Add please lines how do you instantiate the `CLog`

Comment: Show us the code where you are using `CLog`

Comment: `~CLog()` is only run when the variable goes out of scope IIRC

Comment: What is `I declared the class within a void that ends`??

Comment: void foo()
{
 wstring sLogPath;
 sLogPath=GetSpecialFolderDesktop() + L"\\load.log";
 CLog *pLog = new CLog(sLogPath);
 pLog->WriteString(L"Something);
}

Comment: When allocating objects with `new`, they will be deallocated/destroyed when you call `delete` on their pointers (and unless you do, you will have a resource leak).

Comment: Like this?  delete(pLog);   ?

Comment: Yes, or just `delete pLog;`

Comment: @tmighty It's a good lesson, don't use `new` unless you have a good reason. If you hadn't used new and just created the object as a normal variable you would not have had this problem.

Comment: Not related with your problem but when you write `wstring m_sPath=L""` you declare a global variable `m_sPath`. It's not clear what your goal is. If you want to initialize `CLog::m_sPath`, do it in the constructor; and since the default initialization is an empty string, don't do it at all. Also, why is `m_sText` declared as a global variable too?

Comment: @tmighty: Note that you can edit your question to include more information (there is a link at the bottom of the question). I copied your usage example into the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are instantiating dynamically the `CLog`. In that case, you need to delete it explicitly. 
If you create it on the stack `Clog log(sLogPath)`, the destructor will be called when the object goes out of scope.

Comment: Although the OP didn't originally post the relevant code it was completely predictable that this was the reason.